Can folding expressions for variadic templates be binned, and conversion of argument list to vector used instead?
When folding expressions were introduced in C++ 17 I learnt how to write code for variadic templates using the form:
args OP ...
etc.
Now, generally in programming, when we have a long list of parameters, we use arrays or vectors, on which we can iterate with for or while loop.
I have just learnt that C++ allows to convert the packed argument list of a variadic template to simple vector like this:
template<class ... Args>
void foo()
{
   using arg_type = typename std::common_type_t<Args...>;

   std::vector<arg_type> arr = {args...};
}

Which make me conclude that now, for any variadic template instead of writing a strange code with folding expressions, I can freely iterate on the argument list using vector container.
Also, AFAIU, folding expressions technique allows to call only one binary operator on an argument and remaining folding expression, which is very limiting.
I mean, now I am absolutely free to do whatever I want with the arguments and not only to call some binary operator on them?
For example, I can print my arguments sorted like this:
    template<class ... Args>
    void printSorted(const Args& ... args)
    {
        using arg_type = typename std::common_type_t<Args...>;
        
        vector<arg_type> arg_vec = { args ... };
        
        sort(arg_vec.begin(), arg_vec.end());
        
        for(const auto& a : arg_vec)
        {
            cout << a << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

printSorted(3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 8, 2, 0);

Which I doubt I could do with folding expressions (and even if I could it would look terrible).
Now, for known template type parameters it is even simpler:
template<bool ... args>
int read_binary_value()
{
    const vector<bool> vals = { args ... };
    
    int res = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < vals.size(); ++i)
    {
        res <<= 1;
        res += vals[i];
    }
    
    return res;
}

cout << read_binary_value<1, 0, 1>() << endl;

So am I right that folding expressions technique can now be binned and replaced by much more intuitive and readable technique of iterating over an array of arguments?

For starters, please at least use std::array and not std::vector. Second, both of those limit you to the same argument types. Third, you can loop over a pack using an immediately-unvoked lambda: ([&]{std::cout << args << '\n';}(), ...);.

I'm baffled by the motivation "Which make me conclude that now, for any variadic template instead of writing a strange code with folding expressions, I can freely iterate on the argument list using vector container." Function parameters have specific meaning, purposes, and uses. I've never found myself wanting to "freely iterate" over them. If you want to pass a homogeneous, dynamically sized list of values, you can just make a single function (not a template) taking a suitable range or container parameter. Quantifying over parameters is almost like quantifying over functions...

@KerrekSB thanks for your response. I meant that iterating on the parameter list gives you full freedom as a programmer to write any code using those parameters, whist using fold expressions limits you a lot. After all, the purpose of functions accepting variable list of parameters is to allow to do anything you wish with those parameters - no more and no less. Fold expressions don't allow that.

Indeed, this works for same argument type of all params, which is still an important case. Also in fold expressions you use binary operator which implies that the parameter types are either homogeneous or convertible to each other or to some other type.

"[T]he purpose of functions accepting variable list of parameters is to allow to do anything you wish with those parameters" -- I'm not sure I'd put it like that. Many uses of variadic templates are for generic code that manipulates or forwards the arguments generically, and doesn't really "do anythnig you wish" with them. There may some specific use cases that match your characterization, but I'd say that's not common, nor the motivation for the feature. Even std::min isn't variadic, but instead accepts a (homogeneous) list for its "n-ary form".

"are either homogeneous or convertible to each other" Not if the operator is ,, as in the example above.

cout uses left-shift operator, so, that one is the simplest use case for fold expressions: (cout << ... << args)<<"\n";. Fold expressions allow for using multiple signatures for the different input types, while the suggested range approach limits the signature to only one(all arguments are converted to same type). The comma operator (,) can handle most of the less intuitive cases.


So am I right that folding expressions technique can now be binned and replaced by much more intuitive and readable technique of iterating over an array of arguments?

No; all use cases you've shown work with "homogeneous packs" only.
These are packs where all arguments have the same type, or are convertible to the same type.

using arg_type = typename std::common_type_t<Args...>;
std::vector<arg_type> arr = {args...};


This is obviously going to fail if there isn't a common type that all arguments are convertible to.
For example, if Args is int* and float*.
Fold expressions are much more powerful because they work even when there is no common type, such as in:
#include <iostream>

void print(const auto&... args) {
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}

int main() {
    print(1, 3.5, "awoo"); // prints 13.5awoo
}

args can be a string, integer, pointer, etc., all in one pack.
If you have a homogeneous pack, you typically don't need variadic templates at all and can simply use std::array or std::initializer_list.
Also note that there is always a cost to wrapping a pack up in a container first.
std::vector may have to dynamically allocate memory, which can be quite expensive.

yes, indeed, I meant homogeneous pack, sorry I was too generalizing.

But fold expressions will also fail if you pass different param types, e.g.: function add(1, 2, string("abc")) will fail also with fold expressions.

@AndreyRubliov only if you try to put it all into a std::vector or something. I've added an example of a heterogeneous pack to this answer. The example would be impossible to do if you had to dump everything into a std::vector first.

You are right, thanks for this. In fact it is shame that there is no language feature which would allow to iterate on the variable parameter list where on each iteration you would get type and value. What if in your example you need to print every second or third parameter or do some other complex manipulation on them?

@AndreyRubliov you can fold over the comma and manipulate variables within a fold expression, and you can use lambdas within the fold. It's sometimes tricky, but fold expressions are much more powerful than you think. You can sort packs as well if you really want to, it's just quite annoying and complicated. Some people have proposed constexpr for, and there's also pack indexing in C++26, so it's getting more ergonomic over time.
